# How to Implement Acceptance test with Codeception on Javascript Page

Tags: php, testing, codeception, acceptance-testing

I am currently working on test solutions, so far I have been implementing:

- **Unit Test**
- **Functional Test**

Both with **Codeception**, a php test framework.

I want to run an acceptance test but the `phpBrowser` module is for non `javasript` pages.

I came accross **Phantomjs** and **Selenium**.

I am asking which solution is better, before jumping into the code.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is a set of different software tools each with a different approach to supporting test automation.

It allow to mimic the user interaction with the application, it can be well coupled with codeception as well.

it uses the webDriver of codeception as shown on this example:

[codeception website with selenium](http://codeception.com/11-20-2013/webdriver-tests-with-codeception.html)

On the other hand:

PhantomJS is a headless alternative to Selenium Server that implements the WebDriver protocol. It allows you to run Selenium tests on a server without a GUI installed.

[As seen here](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver)